# Xterm cd command not working in launch option

Tags: bash, xterm, cd-command

When I launch xterm with the following command:
`xterm -e 'cd ~' -hold`
A new xterm window pops up saying: `xterm: Can't execvp cd ~: No such file or directory`
After which the xterm window is still in my current directory, where I can run `cd ~` manually, which behaves as expected. Any ideas what might cause this? Or if there is another way to change the starting directory of xterm.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `man xterm` where the `-e` option is documented (emphasis mine):

> -e program [ arguments ... ]
>
> This option specifies the program (and its command line arguments) to be run in the xterm window.  It also sets the window title and icon name to be the basename of the program being executed if neither -T nor -n are given on the command line.
>
> **NOTE: This must be the last option on the command line.**

As you can see, the `-e` *must* be the last option passed on the command line. So `xterm -hold -e 'cd ~'` will work, it will just be useless since the terminal will run the `cd` and then immediately exit the shell session because that's what `-e` means: run the command and exit.

So you need to both `cd` *and* start a new shell. So try this:

```
xterm -hold -e 'cd ~; bash'
```

[Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas) made a very good point in a comment I am reproducing here:

> Note that with `xterm -hold -e 'cd ~; bash'`, xterm still tries to run a command called `cd ~; bash`. It will likely fail but in that case, because we're in the ambiguous case where only one argument is passed after `-e`, it falls back to executing `$SHELL` with `-c` and `cd ~; bash` as arguments. Here, to remove that ambiguity, you should rather do `xterm -hold -e sh -c 'cd && exec bash'`. See also `xterm -hold -e env -C ~ bash` with some `env` implementations.

So, better use:

```
xterm -hold -e sh -c 'cd && exec bash'
```

Answer (score 1):

```bash
( cd && xterm )
```

The most common way of setting the correct working directory for a command is to `cd` before invoking the command.  Doing so in a subshell ensures that the working directory is not changed for the invoking shell.

The command at the top of this answer starts a subshell and then uses `cd` to change the working directory to the home directory of the current user.  If that succeeds, `xterm` is invoked. When `xterm` is invoked without `-e`, it, by default, starts an interactive shell.

Control is given back to the invoking shell when `xterm` terminates (or immediately if `cd` fails).  The `xterm` terminal terminates whenever the command it is running terminates, i.e. when the interactive shell is done.  Use `&` at the end to start the subshell with `xterm` in the background.